# How to give a .tf file as input in Terraform Apply command?

Tags: terraform, devops, open-source, infrastructure-as-code, hashicorp

I'm a beginner in Terraform.

I have a directory which contains 2 .tf files.

Now I want to run Terraform Apply on a selected .tf file & neglect the other one.

Can I do that? If yes, how? If no, why & what is the best practice?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: Just keep in mind: using the `-target` command gives in the terminal: `The -target option is not for routine use, and is provided only for exceptional situations such as recovering from errors or mistakes, or when Terraform specifically suggests to use it as part of an error message.`

But i'm also trying to figure out how to generate stuff based on files vs based on directories and running the `terraform init` everytime ... or maybe i'm not familiar with the "best practice" on how to achieve it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't selectively apply one file and then the other. Two ways of (maybe) achieving what you're going for:

- Use the [`-target`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#target-resource) flag to target resource(s) in one file and then the other.
- Put each file (or more broadly, group of resources, which might be multiple files) in separate "modules" (folders). You can then `apply` them separately.

Comment: Thanks, following second approach.

Comment: this gives out the same warning: "The -target option is not for routine use, and is provided only for exceptional situations". The goal instead is to use separate configurations. Can someone maybe provide a good example and explain implications to remote state/ locking, if any?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `terraform -target` flag. Or
You can have multiple terraform modules in a separate directory. And then you can `terraform apply` there.
As an example, assume you have 3 .tf files separately. But you need to run more than just one of them at the same time. If you also, need to run them more often it's better to have a terraform module.

```
terraform
    |--frontend
    |  └──main.tf
    |--backend-1
    |  └──main.tf
    |--backend-2
    |  └──main.tf
    |--modules-1
    |  └──module.tf
```

Inside the **module.tf** you can define which files you need to apply.

```
module "frontend" {
  source = "terraform/frontend"
}

module "backend-1" {
  source = "terraform/backend-1"
}
```

Then issue `terraform apply` staying at the module directory. And it will automatically import instances inside those paths and apply it.

Answer (score 6):

Putting each terraform config file into separate directory did the job correctly.
So here, is my structure

```
├── aws
│   └── aws_terraform.tf
├── trash
│   └── main.tf
```

All you have to do:

1. enter each folder
2. terraform init && terraform plan && terraform apply
3. enter 'yes' to confirm terraform apply

PS: '-target'  key didn't help me out.

Answer (score 4):

Either use a `--target` option to specify module to run by using below command

```
terraform apply -target=module.<module_name>
```

Or another workaround is rename other terraform files with `*.tf.disable` extension to skip it by loading via Terraform. Currently it's [Code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/config/import_tree.go) loading `*.tf` files

Answer (score 1):

If you cant have terraform files in different folders like the other answers stated. You can try using my script [GitHub repo for script](https://github.com/brunogomes1/tfmess)

Which is a script that runs throughout a specific terraform file and outputs adds "-target=" to all modules names.

Answer (score 1):

This is a filler for the `data` block, as others have already explained `resource` block

You can also *target* `data` block if you're performing a read operation.

Lets say you have two files - `create.tf` and `read.tf`

Assuming `create.tf` is already applied:

```
resource "hashicups_order" "edu" {
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 3
    }
    quantity = 3
  }
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 2
    }
    quantity = 1
  }
}

output "edu_order" {
  value = hashicups_order.edu
}
```

And you only want to apply `read.tf`:

```
data "hashicups_ingredients" "first_coffee" {
  coffee_id = hashicups_order.edu.items[0].coffee[0].id
}

output "first_coffee_ingredients" {
  value = data.hashicups_ingredients.first_coffee
}
```

You can create a plan file targeting the read only data block:

`terraform plan -target=data.hashicups_ingredients.first_coffee`

And similarly, *apply* the read operation using Terraform:

`terraform apply -target=data.hashicups_ingredients.first_coffee -auto-approve`

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, **Terraform** doesn't have the feature to apply **a selected .tf file**. **Terraform** applies **all .tf files** in the same directory.

But you can apply **the selected code** with **comment out** and **uncomment**. For example, you have 2 .tf files **"1st.tf"** and **"2nd.tf"** in the same directory to create the resources for **GCP(Google Cloud Platform)**:

[image]

Then, **"1st.tf"** has this code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-113738"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

And **"2nd.tf"** has this code below:

```js
resource "google_service_account" "service_account_1" {
  display_name = "Service Account 1"
  account_id   = "service-account-1"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account_2" {
  display_name = "Service Account 2"
  account_id   = "service-account-2"
}
```

Now, first, you want to only apply the code in **"1st.tf"** so you need to **comment out** the code in **"2nd.tf"**:

**1st.tf**:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-113738"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

**2nd.tf (Comment Out)**:

```py
# resource "google_service_account" "service_account_1" {
#   display_name = "Service Account 1"
#   account_id   = "service-account-1"
# }

# resource "google_service_account" "service_account_2" {
#   display_name = "Service Account 2"
#   account_id   = "service-account-2"
# }
```

Then, you apply:

```html
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Next, additionally, you want to apply the code in **"2nd.tf"** so you need to **uncomment** the code in **"2nd.tf"**:

**1st.tf**:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-113738"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

**2nd.tf (Uncomment)**:

```py
resource "google_service_account" "service_account_1" {
  display_name = "Service Account 1"
  account_id   = "service-account-1"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account_2" {
  display_name = "Service Account 2"
  account_id   = "service-account-2"
}
```

Then, you apply:

```html
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

This way, you can apply **the selected code** with **comment out** and **uncomment**.